# Conveying 'Get a life'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, langage-informel

The phrase "Get a life" is an idiomatic expression often used as a colloquial and somewhat informal way of telling someone to find or pursue more interesting or meaningful activities, to stop being preoccupied with trivial matters, or to encourage them to have a more fulfilling existence. It can imply that the person should focus on their own life and stop being overly concerned with others or with insignificant issues.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_a_life_(idiom)

Example:

Person A: "I can't believe she spent the whole weekend just watching TV. Doesn't she have anything else to do?"
Person B: "Come on, she really needs to get a life and find some cool stuff to do instead of being glued to the TV all the time."

Example 2:

You guys should just stop moaning and get a life!

Example 3:

Person A: "Why does John always meddle in other people's business? He's always giving unsolicited advice."
Person B: "Yeah, he seriously needs to get a life and stop worrying about everyone else's problems."

Can one use 'Trouve-toi une vie !" ou 'occupe-toi de ta vie ' ?

Comment: "Occupe toi de ta vie" wouldn't sound at all like "Get a life". It would rather sound as "Stop being nosy about others people life and bother about yours".
"trouve toi une vie" would work.

Comment: I find your first paragraph overly charitable for the expression "get a life". I haven't really ever heard this expression used to "encourage [someone] to have a more fulfilling existence". Rather I've heard it used to make fun of something that someone has just said or done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_a_life) donne de manière non étayée « va t'acheter une vie », qui donne un bon nombre de résultats sur le Web. Avec le verbe *trouver* je pense qu'on a surtout « trouve-toi quelque chose d'autre à faire », ou « t'as pas quelque chose d'autre à faire », « t'as rien de mieux à faire (dans la vie) que... » etc., un peu différent mais qu'on entend dans ce genre de contexte. Mais « arrêtez de chialer et allez vous acheter une vie » est un peu bizarre au pluriel à mon avis. Peut-être « ...faites quelque chose de votre vie ».

Comment: Jamais entendu _allez vous acheter une vie_. _faites quelque chose de votre vie_: oui, très bien.

Comment: @Frank Il y a quelques résultats dans Books, mais semble-t-il plus de 14000 sur Search. Je pense l'avoir déjà entendu, mais je trouve que ça ressemble un peu à un calque, c'est peut-être plus présent au Québec. Je n'ai pas fait une longue recherche là-dessus.

Comment: Ouais, c'est bizarre, "acheter une vie" ne sonne pas naturel. Je ne perçois pas d'affinité entre "acheter" et "vie", c'est pas deux mots qu'on mettrait ensemble en français à mon avis, sauf si c'est une nouvelle tendance dans certains milieux...

Comment: @Frank J'ai pas mal entendu "*va t'acheter une vie*" quand j'étais au collège/lycée, de la part de personnes du même âge. Je la classerais dans les expressions d'ado, les options de répartie pour répondre à un "loser". Un peu dans la même veine que les "*parle à ma main*" etc. Ça m'étonnerait pas qu'aucune des deux ne soient encore utilisées par les jeunes de nos jours ^^

Answer (score 2):

Voici comment j'aurais traduit vos exemples:

Exemple 1:

Person A:
"I can't believe she spent the whole weekend just watching TV. Doesn't she have anything else to do?"
Person B: "Come on, she really needs to get a life and find some cool stuff to do instead of being glued to the TV all the time."
A - « Je n'arrive pas à croire qu'elle ait passé son week-end à regarder la télé. Elle [n']a vraiment rien de mieux à faire ? » (or "N'a-t-elle vraiment rien de mieux à faire")
B - « Clairement, il faut qu'**elle se bouge** un peu et se trouve des trucs intéressants à faire plutôt que de passer son temps scotchée à la télé. »

Exemple 2:

"You guys should just stop moaning and get a life!"

This one is harder to translate because it depends on the context. What does "get a life" convey here? 1. "Bugger off" or 2. "Do something about it"?

1. « Arrêtez de vous plaindre et allez vous faire voir. » (or: « ... allez vous faire cuire un oeuf »)
2. « Si vous n'êtes pas content vous n'avez qu'à le faire vous-même. » (If you are not happy [with whatever you complain about] you may as well do it yourself)

Exemple 3:

Person A: "Why does John always meddle in other people's business? He's always giving unsolicited advice."
Person B: "Yeah, he seriously needs to get a life and stop worrying about everyone else's problems."

A - « Pourquoi Jean doit-il toujours se méler des affaire des autres ? Il n'arrête pas de donner son avis sans qu'on ne le lui demande. »
B - « Wai, [il] faut vraiment qu'**il s'occupe de ses affaires**. »

Here is *s'occuper de ses affaires* how I would translate *get a life* in this context. But it also means *stop caring about everyone else's problems*.

Answer (score 2):

*Achete-toi une vie* est bien une réplique méprisante déjà entendue en France au collège ou au lycée (il y a quelques années).

On a un exemple dans l'actualité, la réponse du réalisateur Ridley Scott à des critique sur la véracité historique de son *Napoléon* qui est traduite "achete-toi une vie" ou "achetez-vous une vie" dans la plupart des médias.

> At the Battle of the Pyramids, “Napoleon didn’t shoot at the pyramids”; Marie-Antoinette “famously had very cropped hair for the execution, and, hey, Napoleon wasn’t there.”
>
> Scott’s response: **“Get a life.”**

https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2023/11/13/ridley-scott-director-profile

> Aux Etats-Unis, c'est Dan Snow, historien star de télévision, qui a dénoncé certaines des inexactitudes dans une vidéo TikTok. Et ça, ça n'a pas plu à Ridley Scott. Interrogé sur ces critiques par le New Yorker, le cinéaste répond sans sourciller : **"Mais achète-toi une vie !"**

https://www.premiere.fr/Cinema/News-Cinema/Achete-toi-une-vie--Ridley-Scott-semporte-contre-un-historien-qui-critique-Napoleon

On est un peu dans la même veine qu'un "va t'acheter un cerveau", par exemple.

Pourquoi "acheter" et non "trouver" ou "obtenir", sans doute par une petite couche de méchanceté additionnelle : impliquer que la personne est tellement nulle qu'elle ne saurait obtenir ce qui lui manque autrement qu'en l'achetant.